# Способ получения данных из CSV-файла для записи в бд и замены данных из других таблиц в столбцах с внешним ключом

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, csv, insert

У меня 3 таблицы в SQL Server, я беру файл CSV с данными и записываю в эти 3 таблицы. Данные проверяются чтобы отсечь дублирующие. В две таблицы заносятся без проблем. А в таб. где необходимо по внешнему ключу добавлять из двух других id который (FK), выдает ошибку.
Необходима помощь.

```cs
private void insertInTab()
    {

        try
        {
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionMSSQLServer);

            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();

            sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;

            const string strQueryRechnung = @"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Menge, Einheit, BetragBrutto, Beginn, Ende, tblFkto.IdFKTO, tblGeraet.Id_Geraet
                                                                FROM tblRechnung, tblFkto, tblGeraet
                                                                WHERE 
                                                                      tblFkto.FKTO = @FKTO
                                                                AND   tblGeraet.Bezeichnung = @Bezeichnung
                                                                AND   Menge = @Menge
                                                                AND   Einheit = @Einheit
                                                                AND   BetragBrutto = @BetragBrutto
                                                                AND   Beginn = @Beginn
                                                                AND   Ende = @Ende) 
                                                               INSERT INTO tblRechnung (Menge, Einheit, BetragBrutto, Beginn, Ende, IdFKTO, IdGeraet) 
                                                               VALUES (@Menge, @Einheit, @BetragBrutto, @Beginn, @Ende, @IdFKTO, @Id_Geraet);";


            using (sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(strQueryRechnung, sqlConnection))
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdFKTO", SqlDbType.Int);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id_Geraet", SqlDbType.Int);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Menge", SqlDbType.Int);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Einheit", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@BetragBrutto", SqlDbType.SmallMoney);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Beginn", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Ende", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                sqlConnection.Open();

                for (int i = 2; i < dgvCSVRechnung.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    sqlCommand.Parameters["@FKTO"].Value = dgvCSVRechnung.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                    sqlCommand.Parameters["@Bezeichnung"].Value = dgvCSVRechnung.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
                    sqlCommand.Parameters["@Menge"].Value = Int32.Parse((string)dgvCSVRechnung.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters["@Einheit"].Value = dgvCSVRechnung.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value;
                    sqlCommand.Parameters["@BetragBrutto"].Value = Decimal.Parse((string)dgvCSVRechnung.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters["@Beginn"].Value = DateTime.ParseExact(dgvCSVRechnung.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString(), "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters["@Ende"].Value = DateTime.ParseExact(dgvCSVRechnung.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString(), "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }

            sqlConnection.Close();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Fehler!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Comment: Ключи генерируются в БД? Насколько я понял вашу проблему, нужно при вставке данных сразу получать ключи обратно. И уже их использовать при вставке в третью таблицу.

Comment: Совершенно правильно поняли

Comment: В одном запросе (батче) делаете `insert` и `select scope_identity()`. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1331158/184217

Comment: Можете пример написать, я еще недавно начал

Comment: Покажите DDL этих трёх таблиц. Все колонки не нужно, оставьте лишь колонки с ключами и одну с информацией. И покажите код c#, как пытаетесь вставить.

Comment: Наверное пошел сложным путем. Сделал временную таблицу Temp, написал Stored Procedure которая делит данные после загрузки а таблицу Temp потом очищается. Но так работает. Вызывается процедура сразу после импорта.